# Pandas: Merge multiple describe() statistics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The [`pandas.DataFrame.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) function calculates statistics for a DataFrame along each of its columns:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

>>> s.describe()
count    3.0
mean     2.0
std      1.0
min      1.0
25%      1.5
50%      2.0
75%      2.5
max      3.0
dtype: float64
```

I have a directory of CSV files, each corresponding to a DataFrame. I want to calculate this statistic for each of these DataFrames, but then also output combined statics for the whole directory. I only need *count/mean/min/max*. Is there any good way to do this, apart from `concat`ing all DataFrames together and calling `describe()` on this gigantic DataFrame?

Comment: `list_of_summaries` is a list of DataFrame's right? List of `df.describe` on every `df` in a directory?

Comment: Would it work to iterate through all CSVs, save each `describe()` as a row in an extra DataFrame and finally calculate min/max as `min()`/`max()`, count as `sum()` and mean as a weighted sum of count and mean?

Comment: Correct @Ch3steR

Comment: @AndreS. Yes but I'm looking for a compact and/or built-in solution

Comment: `apart from concating all DataFrames together and calling describe() on this gigantic DataFrame?` - Do you think not need `concat` all `described` DataFrames like in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so easy, added 2 antother solutions. Differences is with mean, because not exist `mean` of `means`, also `count` is used for exclude missing values, so rather I prefer `size` method:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3)))
dfs = [df, df * 2, df * 3, df * 5]

list_of_summaries = [x.agg(['min','max','size', 'mean','count', 'sum']) for x in dfs]
```

```
df = pd.concat(list_of_summaries, axis=1) 
df = pd.DataFrame([df.loc['min'].min(level=0),
                   df.loc['max'].max(level=0),
                   df.loc['size'].sum(level=0),
                   df.loc['sum'].sum(level=0)])
df.loc['mean'] = df.loc['sum'].div(df.loc['size'])
df = df.drop('sum')
print (df)
              0          1     2
min    0.000000   3.000000   0.0
max   35.000000  40.000000  15.0
size  12.000000  12.000000  12.0
mean  11.916667  17.416667   5.5
```

---

```
df1 = (pd.concat(list_of_summaries, axis=1)
         .T
         .groupby(level=0)
         .agg({'min':'min', 'max':'max', 'size':'sum', 'sum':'sum'})
         .T)
df1.loc['mean'] = df1.loc['sum'].div(df.loc['size'])
df1 = df1.drop('sum')
print (df1)
              0          1     2
min    0.000000   3.000000   0.0
max   35.000000  40.000000  15.0
size  12.000000  12.000000  12.0
mean  11.916667  17.416667   5.5
```

---

```
import functools
import pandas as pd

def reduce_(a, b):
    return pd.DataFrame([
        pd.concat([a.loc['min'], b.loc['min']], axis=1).min(axis=1),
        pd.concat([a.loc['max'], b.loc['max']], axis=1).max(axis=1),
        pd.concat([a.loc['count'], b.loc['count']], axis=1).sum(axis=1),
        pd.concat([a.loc['mean'], b.loc['mean']], axis=1).mean(axis=1),
    ], index=['min', 'max', 'count', 'mean'])

assert len(list_of_summaries) > 0
summary_of_summaries = functools.reduce(reduce_, list_of_summaries)

print (summary_of_summaries)
               0          1      2
min     0.000000   3.000000   0.00
max    35.000000  40.000000  15.00
count  12.000000  12.000000  12.00
mean   15.708333  22.958333   7.25
```

Comment: The use of `.agg` is smart but I feel like there might be a more compact or readable solution in that direction. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach I currently have that does not require combining all data into one huge DataFrame. It's not very readable or efficient but I might as well post it to make clear what I'm looking for:

```py
import functools
import pandas as pd

def reduce_(a, b):
    return pd.DataFrame([
        pd.concat([a.loc['min'], b.loc['min']], axis=1).min(axis=1),
        pd.concat([a.loc['max'], b.loc['max']], axis=1).max(axis=1),
        pd.concat([a.loc['count'], b.loc['count']], axis=1).sum(axis=1),
        # mean is weighted so trickier
    ], index=['min', 'max', 'count'])

assert len(list_of_summaries) > 0
summary_of_summaries = functools.reduce(reduce_, list_of_summaries)
```

The difficulty here essentially is that I need a **different operator for each row** y'know?